# How to get account name from Public or Private key via eosjs?

Tags: accounts, account-name, eosjs, keys, public-key

If I have only a private key, how shold I:
1. Check private key and generate public key
2. Get account name from Public or Private key via eosjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use eosjs `get_key_accounts`. See

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-api/commit/21675aec294d6f65f3cbace049839751a087676f